# What is the 0V reference for MOV's input protection on power supply?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-protection, mov

In some application notes for MOVs I see example usage in power supply design where each input line (N, L) from the mains are protected with a MOV to a ground voltage reference (as well as a differential mode MOV protection between the input lines)

What I don't understand is what is the 0V "ground" reference these application notes are referring to?

It is both regulatory and practically impossible to use the PE (=FG) since even the smallest MOV current could trigger the earth protection circuit breaker.

Comment: *a common-mode MOV protection between the input lines* I'd say that a MOV between live and neutral is **differential mode** protection while the MOVs between Line-Earth and between Live-Earth are for common mode protection.

Comment: The regulations have also changed during the years, and at some point there was a time when equipment with a pluggable mains cord was not considered reliably earthed so it was not compliant to have a MOV connected to earth, and at present a simple MOV must in practice have a GDT in series to prevent leakage (along with thermal protection).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, You are of course correct. I wrote too quickly without thinking. Any common mode charge would raise both MOV terminals and hence have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What I don't understand is what is the 0V "ground" reference these
> application notes are referring to?*

Well, despite you thinking this: -

> *It is both regulatory and practically impossible to use the PE (=FG)
> since even the smallest MOV current could trigger the earth protection
> circuit breaker.*

The answer is still actually the "protective earth" (PE). If a surge causes a live-neutral imbalance current, then it may trip an RCD (UK) or GFCI (US). That cannot be avoided other than by designing the power supply AC interface to not require a protective earth point and hence it's impossible to utilize surge protectors connected to PE.

Comment: Thanks. This is kind of what I suspected. But even in normal operation you would have a small current flowing through the MOV which I believe would be enough to cause inbalance and to trip breaker.

Comment: I don't believe that the small current you talk about will be anywhere close to the normal 30 mA trip limit for an RCD or GFCI.

Comment: You are right (I thought the trip current was lower). The leak would be in the u-range which is well below the range of the trip limit.  But even then my understanding of regulation (in EU) is that a device can not have, by design, even that small leak current in normal operation towards PE.

Comment: Then your "understanding" needs to be upgraded!!